# How to tell which physcal drive is sdc?

Tags: hardware, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I physically identify a single drive in a RAID array?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11088/how-can-i-physically-identify-a-single-drive-in-a-raid-array)

I have a computer with several drives in it, all identical, all part of a RAID. One of those drives is failing (sdc), but I can't tell which physical drive is sdc... any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try sudo fdisk -l ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will output the serial number of the disk, which should be printed on its label:

```
sudo hdparm -i /dev/sdc
```